# Why is std::queue.front() causing an segment fault?

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, memcached, threadpool

Here is the scene:
I'm trying to write a simple multi-thread server using libev, and implement the thread pool model that memcached used, which uses a dispatcher thread and several worker threads(but the problem is not about libev or memcached).

I define a class `WorkerThreadPool` which is like

```
class WorkerThreadPool 
{
//...
private:
    WorkerThread *worker_threads; //worker threads, enough space allocated
};
```

and WorkerThread is struct below(omit some unnecessary fields)

```
typedef struct {
    thread_t tid;
    std::queue<event_entry *> event_queue; //event_entry is irrelavant here
}WorkerThread;
```

Then there is a **private static** member function `eventHandler` in class `WorkerThreadPool`, in which I accesse one of the thread structures(all the threads have been successfully created), as follows

```
WorkerThread *wthread = &worker_threads[0];
if(whtread->event_queue.empty()){
    std::cout << "Empty!\n";
}else{
    std::cout << "Not empty.\n";
    event_entry *evt = wthread->event_queue.front();
    std::cout << "fine.\n";
}
```

However, it crashed right after the "Not empty.\n" output because it didn't print "fine.\n".

At first I thought it is because that static member function can't access non-static members, but **when I change the `worker_threads` to static, the error remains**. I've also tried to modify the `worker_threads` to be public, but no luck.

Now I'm really confused and I've been stuck for days. Could anyone give me some help?

Comment: Do you lock the queue with something like a mutex before reading and writing it?

Comment: Might not be related, but just be careful using buffered output as a debugging tool. If the output buffer wasn't flushed it's possible that your program didn't crash where you thought it did. You could replace those newlines with `std::endl` to ensure the output makes it to the screen before the crash.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yes, there is a mutex in the WorkerThread structure.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I use `pthread_mutex_lock(&wthread->event_queue_lock);` before I call empty(), does the mutex has anything to do with the error? I'm not very familiar with it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would like to but that involves a few other source files and header files, I'm not sure if others would like me to post a question full of codes.

Comment: @TgnYang -- Why do you call `front()`, regardless of whether the queue is empty or not?  *Now I'm really confused and I've been stuck for days* -- It took no more than a minute to see you unconditionally call `front()`.

Comment: @TgnYang -- `&worker_threads[0];` -- What if `worker_threads` is empty?  You are then using a bogus `wThread` pointer.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You're right, I've already modified my answer. The call to empty is added later, I was just trying to see if it is empty, and it output "Not empty." every time. But I admit that this is a bad habit.

Comment: Do you have multiple threads running that last code block?  If so how are you synchronizing everything?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I check the validation of worker_threads before, the whole example involves a few other files so I don't put all of them here.

Comment: @TgnYang -- Well your best options as to what the error is:  1) The `wthread` pointer is invalid, or 2) A thread made the queue empty while you were retrieving the item from the queue.  Take your pick.  Also you use `whtread` in one part of the code, and then `wthread` in another part of the code.  Is this  a typo?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, I'm trying to implement the memcaced thread pool model. As far as I know, worker threads are notified using pipe, the dispatcher threads write to fd_write, and the corresponding worker thread will be notified, and `eventHandler` will be called(by using `ev_io_init` provided by libev library). If my understanding is inaccurate, please kindly point out.

Comment: Well I have never used that so I am not sure but you need to make sure that only one thread at a time inspects the state of the queue and then removes the item.  Otherwise you could have a thread remove a item write after you check `empty` which would cause this problem.

Comment: @TgnYang -- Your routine to remove an item from the queue needs to lock out any other running code that will adjust the queue at the same time you're retrieving from it.  Whatever you're doing, the basic concept should be easy to understand -- don't fuss with the queue, since I'm going to change it by removing an item.

Answer (score 1):

```
event_entry *evt = wthread->event_queue.front();
```

is a problem when the queue is empty.

You need to use:

```
WorkerThread *wthread = &worker_threads[0];
if(whtread->event_queue.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Empty!\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Not empty.\n";
    event_entry *evt = wthread->event_queue.front();
}
std::cout << "fine.\n";
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but actually, it crashed even it outputs "Not empty.". the output before is just to make sure that it is not empty. I'll modify my question so that it is less confusing.